# How to add power button to RPI 3 b+?

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, python-3

I want to make mini computer and I want add button for on/off power button. I will change config.txt with dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown. And then add button between GND and GPIO5. There has written that it will start: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=217442

I read and watched many posts and videos, but I've question - 
Is there risk for burn RPI 3 B+? And is there any way without any risk?

Comment: What makes you think there's a risk of burning the pi? Did you read it somewhere? What's the context?

Comment: I'm afraid that it can burn. Because there is power and it can end with smoke.

Comment: How are you planning to do it?

Comment: I will change config.txt with dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown. And then add button between GND and GPIO5. There has written that it will start.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=217442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you connect a button between GPIO3 and GND and use GPIO3 as an input, there is no danger of you burning the Pi. No significant power goes through the switch - it is a signal only.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90512/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-smith-how-to-add-power-button-to-rpi-3-b).

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit made [Read-Only Raspberry Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/read-only-raspberry-pi/overview) which means you could use the wall socket switch without risk of corruption etc.